# Get MockWebServer port into the Spring container with SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-test, spring-boot-test, mockwebserver

I have a `Spring Boot` + `WebFlux` application with the following structure:

- A controller `ControllerA` that uses a service `ServiceA`.
- `ServiceA` uses a `WebClient` to call a remote microservice `microservice A`.
- The URL of the endpoint in `microservice A` is configurable in `application.yaml`.

Now I would like to test it using `SpringBootTest` and `JUnit 5 Jupiter` with the `PER_CLASS` test lifecycle. For this, I want to mock the remote microservice using OkHttp `MockWebServer`. The server is started before the first test method (`@BeforeAll`) and stopped after all tests (`@AfterAll`).

The problem is that the Spring container starts first, and then the test methods (and their before and after callbacks) are invoked. When the container starts it initializes the beans, and also `ServiceA` with the URL of `microservice A` from `application.yaml`. Only afterwards is `MockWebServer` started and I can query it for its URL, but at that point it's already too late and `ServiceA` is already instantiated with the 'wrong' (real) URL.

I got it to work in various ways using various hacks (e.g. fixing the port by overriding the URL with `@TestPropertySource` and then forcing `WebTestServer` to use this port) but all have disadvantages (what if the port is takes by a parallel CI job?).

As we are only going to have more and more such integration tests in our codebase, we need a good solution for it. I am thinking of writing a custom `TestExecutionListener` running before all of the Spring ones (and starting the mock server), but I'm not sure if this would work (I still don't know yet how I would pass the port to the container, I have never implemented such listeners).

Question: before I implement listeners or some other custom solution I wanted to make sure that I really need to. I searched the web a bit and didn't find anything, but I don't think we are the first team to write such tests, I'm just searching badly. Does anybody know of any kind of library that would solve this problem? Or maybe a neat Spring trick that I'm currently missing but one that would help?

Comment: I've got the same problem ... any luck?

Comment: @dcg Nothing worth mentioning, we are just applying a lot of workaround depending on the use case, or just don't write tests if it's too hard. It's a mess.